# Learn more about the Ramchal's plays

Tags: jewish-books, performance-entertainment, ramchal, literature

Apparently the Ramchal [wrote several plays](http://www.torah.org/learning/ramchal/classes/special2.html).

1. What are they about?
2. Where can I find full text ([I found Migdal Oz here](http://www.benyehuda.org/ramxal/migdal_oz.html) - preferably translated?
3. Have Gedolei Yisroel discussed how to approach these works? i.e. should they be treated as Torah or simply as plays?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by 3. Do you mean a Mesorah?

Comment: @DoubleAA right, see my edits, let me know if that helps.

Comment: You say he wrote several plays, linking to a `torah.org` page, but I only see one play, "_Maase Shimshon_", listed at that page, unless you're counting "_Maamar Havikuach_" as a play. You mention "_Migdal Oz_", but that `torah.org` page, at least, doesn't indicate that that's a play.

Comment: fair point. migdal oz is certainly a play as you can see from the link and as indicated here - http://chardal.blogspot.com/2006/11/rare-ramchal-play-now-on-net.html I was told verbally that the Ramchal wrote others but have not found a list of them online

Comment: The site you link to for "_Migdal Oz_" does, however, have ["_Maase Shimshon_"](http://www.benyehuda.org/ramxal/maase_shimshon.html), a play, also. (I can't vouch for the site's accuracy of reproduction)

Comment: Here's Shimshon: http://benyehuda.org/ramxal/maase_shimshon.html

Comment: @msh210 According to the Reader's Encyclopedia of World Drama, Maase Shimshon, Migdal Oz and laYesharim Tehilla were all dramas, though not necessarily written for theater. http://books.google.com/books?id=oPOQf26l-PEC&pg=PA471&lpg=PA471&dq=maase+shimshon&source=bl&ots=Q3D-JKURQ0&sig=13X5hMN3uws8L3GzCqdTVLTfJMw&hl=en&sa=X&ei=BOlPT4nEHITX0QHA59y_DQ&ved=0CCcQ6AEwAg#v=onepage&q=maase%20shimshon&f=false

Comment: Are 1 and 2 on topic?

Comment: @DoubleAA from what I have learned the plays were another way for the Ramchal to teach sodei hatorah in a concealed fashion (like Rebbi Nachman's stories) so I think #1 is on topic and as much as any question about finding torah online is on topic so would #2. I think #3 should be reworded to avoid quibbling about 'Gedolei Yisroel'