# Pairs of the Ramchal's works

Tags: history, jewish-books, publications, ramchal

Machon Ofek has published the Ramchal's Mesillas Yesharim (MY) as well as what they call The Mesillas Yesharim- Seder Vikuach which is essentially the same as the commonly known MY but in dialogue form between a chacham and a chassid (written by the Ramchal a few years prior to publishing the MY).
I have read that the Ramchal wrote several books this way, first as a dialogue and then as a conclusion of principles. My question is: what other works, that we have, did the Ramchal write in this way?

Comment: Daat tevunot (dialogue), Derech Hashem (principles)

Comment: related http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/14872/759

Comment: חוקר ומקובל, 
I forgot the two names.

Comment: @wfb How do you know that?

Comment: @Gavriel,actually I got it wrong - it's דעת תבונות & ספר הכללים

Comment: @wfb I see... but again, what makes you say that?

Comment: see e.g. https://he.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D7%A8%D7%9E%D7%97%22%D7%9C#.D7.A1.D7.A4.D7.A8.D7.99.D7.95